# Exceptions are simply not caught by PostSharp

Tags: postsharp

Well, I don't get it. Trying to apply a PostSharp attribute for exception handling on a method, the aspect's OnException method is simply not reached by any means. This is very disappointing.
For the sake of testing, let's say this is the aspect:

```
[PSerializable]
public class HandleExceptionsAttribute : OnExceptionAspect
{
    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        Trace.TraceError(args.Exception.Message);            
        args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Return;
    }
}
```

And it is applied on a method that only throws an exception:

```
[HandleExceptions]
public static void Test()
{
    throw new Exception("Test");
}
```

Well, nothing happens. The aspect's OnException method is never reached at all (via debugging or otherwise).

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have the PostSharp NuGet package installed in your project? (PostSharp.Redist is not enough.) Do you call the Test method? Do you have PostSharp Tools for Visual Studio installed? If none of these helps, could you please share the complete example including the .csproj project file?

Comment: Thank you @AntonínProcházka, indeed it was the PostSharp Tools not installed. Out of curiosity, do you know why it is needed? It strikes me as a bit strange that the package won't be enough, and I don't love this dependency - now every team member would have to manually install it...?

Comment: It is needed to keep the debugging experience, especially debugging of the aspect code. The compiled assembly works correctly even without having this tooling installed. You can also take advantage of other features like knowing which code is enhanced by PostSharp. See https://blog.postsharp.net/post/postsharp-6-9-rc-visual-studio-tooling-performance-improvements.html for details. For mass deployment, you can take advantage of silent installation: https://doc.postsharp.net/installation-silent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the PostSharp NuGet package installed, the aspect code should be reached, but break-points within the aspect code might not be reached. You need to have PostSharp Tools for Visual Studio installed to make debugging of aspect code work. You can download it at https://www.postsharp.net/download.